# Matlab: How can I superimpose a scatterplot onto the barweb function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, scatter

I'm currently using the barweb function in matlab to plot the average reaction time of each group. I would like to also superimpose the individual reaction times above each bar. How can I do this?

This is my current code:

```
      figure;barweb(errorscores.mu(3:4,:), errorscores.sem(3:4,:));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using `hold on` and then `scatter`?

Comment: When I do hold on scatter, the scatter plots are not aligned in the same group.

Comment: Can you provide a sample picture/dataset so that we could see the precise problem with `hold on` ? Because this is definitively the way to go.